# exclude project from GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two sub projects in my repo.
The First one is .Net 5, The second is SharePoint solution. Both projects located in one branch.
How to configure pipeline only for one project?

I need to pass SAST test only for .Net 5 project. Now both projects are testing.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
- test

sast:
  stage: test
  tags:
  - docker
```

Answer (score 0):

First off - putting multiple projects into a single repo is a bad idea.

Second, the Gitlab SAST template is meant to be "simple to use", but it's very complex under the hood and utilizes a number of different SAST tools.

You ***do*** have some configuration options available via variables, but those are mostly specific to the language/files you are scanning. For some languages there are variables available that can limit which directories/paths are being scanned.

Since you haven't provided enough information to make a specific recommendation, you can look up the variables you need for your project(s) in the official docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#available-cicd-variables

Comment: Isn't `putting multiple projects into one branch` what one would call a monorepo?

Answer (score -1):

If each Project, can have specific branch names, you can use
[only--except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#only--except) or [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keywords to determine when jobs should run.

```
sast:
  stage: test
  tags:
  - docker
  only:
    - /^sast-.*$/
```

It is for specific jobs, not sure about whole pipeline.

Comment: No, there are two projects in one branch.